# How to get activated current `b:keymap_name` value

Tags: vimscript, statusline

I have a below line

```
set keymap = russian-jcukenwin.vim
```

in `.vimrc`.

When I press `C-^` I get indicator in mode line , like `INSERT (RU)`.

I'd like to output it in lightline vim config, and there is `%k` flag for this, but  is there a different way to get the current value?

When I try below (to call it in lightline configuration)

```
function! CurrentKeymap() abort
    let l:current = toupper(b:keymap_name)
    return l:current
endfunction
```

it always returns `RU` - even if keymap is not activated (with `C-^`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also `:h iminsert` you can use to check if keymap is active:

```
function! CurrentKeymap() abort
    return &iminsert ? toupper(b:keymap_name) : ""
endfunction
```